# Algebra that is closed under countable increasing unions is a sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I guess this is equivalent to say algebra that is monotone(increasing) class is a sigma-algebra.

However, can anyone tell me how to prove it? Till now I can't think of any construction or partition of sets to prove the the closure of **countable** unions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** Given $\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ in your algebra, consider $B_n=\bigcup_{k<n}A_k$.

Comment: Should I reason it in this way? $B_n$ is in the algebra if $n$ is finite. Because of the monotone(increasing) property, the countable unions of $B_n$ is also in the algebra. so limit of $B_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity will also be in the algebra, which implies it's a sigma-algebra as well.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds fine.

Comment: Why does the limit should be in the algebra?

Comment: @user162343: Try and prove that.

Comment: Well, I think is because once you know that your algebra is closed under countable increasing unions, you get a sequence of nested sets, and then you can conclude that the limit (that is the increasing union of that sequence you defined as $B_n$) should be in the algebra, right?

Comment: @user162343: Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: Right, so the proof is complete :)